# Use variable from one class to another in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a quiz game and have some troubles with the variables in the StartGamePanel. I have start game panel, game over panel and main menu panel. My score variable in the start game panel is initially 0 but for every user's correct answer it goes 100 more points. My idea is in the game over panel if user give wrong answer to show him what was his total points. But unfortunately the score variable is stands 0. In the start game panel the game UI shows correctly scores and the logic is working and add 100 points for every correct answer but when i try to use score variable in the game over panel it is 0 every time. This is my StartGamePanel:

```
public class StartGamePanel extends JPanel {
...
private GameData gameData;

public StartGamePanel(Frame frame, GameData gameData) {
    this.frame = frame;
    this.gameData = gameData;
    ...//creating the upper panel and set defaults for the panel

    //label for time
    timeLabel = new JLabel("Time: " + gameData.getTime());
    timeLabel.setFont(font);
    timeLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    /** updating the timeLabel */
    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (gameData.getStartTime() > 0) {
                //getStartTime -= 1000;
                //time--;
                gameData.updateStartTime(-1000);
                gameData.updateTime(-1);
                if (gameData.getTime() == 0) {
                    frame.swapView("gameover");
                }
                timeLabel.setText("Time: " + gameData.getTime());
                timeLabel.repaint();
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();

    //getting instance of QuestionRandomizer;       
    QuestionRandomizer qRand = new QuestionRandomizer();


    /*question 1 panel*/
    //------------------
    //------------------
    //------------------
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    card1.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 43));
    Question q1 = qRand.getRandomQuestion();

    //label for the first question
    JLabel question1Label = new JLabel(q1.getText());
    question1Label.setFont(questionLabelsFont);
    question1Label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    //gbc for question1Label
    ...

    card1.add(question1Label, gbc2);

    //Panel holding buttons
    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));


    //Answer buttons

    JButton answer1 = new JButton(q1.getAnswers()[0].getText()+ "");
    answer1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (q1.getAnswers()[0].getIsCorrect() == true) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
            cl.show(cards, "question2");

            //updating the scores
            gameData.updateScore(100);
            scoresLabel.setText("Scores: " + gameData.getScore());
            scoresLabel.repaint();

            //updating the timer
            timer.stop();
            gameData.setTime(16);
            gameData.setStartTime(16*1000);
            timer.start();
            }       

            //IF THE ANSWER IS INCORRECT GO TO THE GAMEOVER PANEL!!!
            if (q1.getAnswers()[0].getIsCorrect() == false) {
                frame.swapView("gameover");
            }
        }       
    });
    //I have 3 more buttons for the answers in this question card and more questions  cards but the logic is the same for everything.
    public GameData getGameData() {
    return this.gameData;
}
```

Take a look at my game over panel:

```
public class GameOverPanel extends JPanel {
private StartGamePanel sgp;
private JLabel gameOverLabel;
private GameData gameData;

public GameOverPanel(StartGamePanel sgp) {
    this.sgp = sgp;
    this.gameData = sgp.getGameData(); // i created a method in the start game panel which returns start game panel's gameData object
    //default settings
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    this.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 43));
    this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));


    gameOverLabel = new JLabel("");


    gameOverLabel.setText("<html><h1>You didn't answer correctly!</h1><hr><h2></h2><h3>Your score: " + gameData.getScore() + "</h3></html>");

    gameOverLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    //constraints for the gameoverlabel
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    this.add(gameOverLabel, gbc);

}
}
```

And the MainFrame class switching over the panels:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
GameData gameData = new GameData();
MainMenu menuPanel = new MainMenu(this);
StartGamePanel startPanel = new StartGamePanel(this, gameData);
GameOverPanel gameOverPanel = new GameOverPanel(startPanel);


public Frame() {
    this.setLayout(cl);
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    //this.setEnabled(true);


    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    int screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    this.setLocation((screenWidth - getWidth()) / 2, (screenHeight - getHeight()) / 2);

    this.add(menuPanel, "menu");
    this.add(startPanel, "start");
    this.add(gameOverPanel, "gameover");
    swapView("menu");
}

public void swapView(String view) {
    cl.show(getContentPane(), view);
}
}
```

Comment: This is too much code to expect someone to read. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you show the code where you create your GameOverPanel?

Comment: Downvote for too much code. Please extract just the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't modeled your problem domain correctly. That's why you are facing this problem. You should keep `question`, `score`, `time`, etc in a separate domain class (say `GameData`), not in the `JPanel` class.

In the event handler of user's starting the game, you should first create an instance of `GameData` and then pass that instance to your `StartGamePanel` panel class, say, as a constructor argument. Similarly, in the event handler of user's ending the game, you should use the same instance of `GameData` as you passed to spg and pass it to `GameOverPanel`.

**Edit**:

Based on the further information you have provided, here is what you need to do in addition to the above suggestion of separating the game data to an independent GameData class:

Add a new setter method in the `GameOverPanel` class.

```
public void setGameData(GameData gd) {
    this.gameData = gd;
}
```

Add a new getter method in the `startGamepanel` class.

```
public void getGameData() {
    return gamedata;
}
```

Update the `swapView` method in the main frame class to following:

```
public void swapView(String view) {
    if("gameover".equals(view)) {
         gameOverPanel.setGameData(startPanel.getGameData());
    }
    cl.show(getContentPane(), view);
    gameOverLabel.setText("<html><h1>You didn't answer correctly!</h1><hr><h2></h2><h3>Your score: " + gameData.getScore() + "</h3></html>");

}
```

Comment: i create a new class holding the variables and make it work for my start game panel but i dont know how to use the same instance in the game over panel. Can you give more info?

Comment: For that you need to show your revised code. Particularly the method where create the start panel and end panel and how you pass them the `GameData` instance.

Comment: Also i made a method in the start game panel which return `this.gameData` (this is the instance of GameData class) and try to pass this in the game over panel. Is this the right direction to do this?

Comment: So i need to make a new topic or i can show it in the answers section?

Comment: Try to do it by editing your question. Show only minimal and yet necessary code.

Comment: @j.DOE: keep removing all which is not needed for the purpose of the question :)

Comment: @j.DOE, your revision is better now. There's an important thing that we don't understand though. When exactly the game is started and when exactly it is getting over? When exactly is the switch from start panel to over panel done?

Comment: If user clicks on a button labeled with a wrong answer i use swapView method which swaps to the game over panel. This method is in the Frame class below

Comment: @j.DOE, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks. See my edited answer. Hopefully it will fix your problem.

Comment: @VHS the constructor in the game over panel remains the same?

Comment: @j.DOE, you don't need the statement `this.gameData = sgp.getGameData();` in that constructor because it's not going to serve anything. But having it there won't harm you. It's just that it is useless.

Comment: @VHS Ok i did everything you pointed out in your edited answer but  the compilator in `gameOverLabel.setText("<html><h1>You didn't answer correctly!</h1><hr><h2></h2><h3>Your score: " + gameData.getScore() + "</h3></html>");`  points out NullPointerException. Maybe this gameData.getScore() is not initialized?

Comment: No, that just means either `gameData` is null or `gameOverLabel` is null. Can you debug and find out which one is null?

Comment: @VHS i think the problem is in gameData because when i change the text in gameOverLabel to `gameOverLabel.setText("<html><h1>You didn't answer correctly!</h1><hr><h2></h2><h3>Your score: " + sgp.getGameData().getScore() + "</h3></html>");` there is no null exception but the score is still 0 :)

Comment: @j.DOE, I see that you are calling this statement in the constructor of the `GameOverPanel` class. You cannot have it there because you construct the GameOverPanel even before the game has started. So at that point, there is no game data available which throws a null pointer exception. You need move that statement to `swapView` method right after you load the game over panel. See my edits.

Comment: @VHS It worked finally but have to change `private JLabel gameOverLabel` in the GameOverPanel to just `JLabel gameOverLabel`. Thank you dude for all of your patience and experience. And sorry for ruining your day with my bullshits :)

Comment: @j.DOE, I am glad that I was able to help you. No, you haven't ruined my day at all. In fact your appreciation has already made my day. On a side note, I would recommend that you learn all the changes you made to make your program working and more importantly understand why they were necessary.  On the same note, you need to understand why removing the access modifier `private` was necessary. Hint: when you do that, you make `gameOverLabel` package-private. You need to learn why it was necessary. What else could you have done?